# How to count the number of people when time equal to 120 seconds during evacuation using the function in anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am working on fire evacuation of a building floor and would like to count the number of people remaining inside the building after 120 seconds? The timer should start once the evacuation process begins, which is by alarm that goes off after a certain amount of time using an event feature.

I know how to count the total number of people inside the building using the function component getPeopleInsideCount and a text with getPeopleInsideCount().  But I don't know what code to use for my problem.

Below is the code:

```
return pedOffice.countPeds() + pedStudents.countPeds()  - pedSink.sink.count();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this, it will count the people in the building floor and it will stop counting after 120 seconds...

Step 1: 
create an event with trigger type timeout, and mode: user control, and timeout=120 seconds.

Step 2:

- create a variable called stopCounting as a boolean with initial value false
- create a variable called peopleRemaining as an int

Step 3: 
when the evacuation begins run the code:

```
event.restart();
```

Step 4:
in your event use the following code:

```
stopCounting=true;
peopleRemaining=getPeopleInsideCount();
```

Step 5
In your text use the following code instead of getPeopleInsideCount()

```
stopCounting ? peopleRemaining : getPeopleInsideCount()
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much!!!!!!!! I had to change one thing though, variable for peopleRemaining has to be in long because my getPeopleInsideCount function was in long.

Answer (score 1):

Add a dynamic event that returns the count you need.

Once your alarm goes off, you can call that dynamic event 120 seconds later using `create_MyDynamicEvent(120, SECOND);`

That will execute the event code 120 seconds later.

cheers

Comment: Hi Sir, I've added the code to my alarm timer (which is another event) and included the dynamic event with the code 
```getPeopleInsideCount();```  in the action But it doesn't seem to do anything because my text still counts the number of people exceeding 120 seconds. Do I make any changes to my function body? Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: please provide more details, it is not clear what elements you have and how they interact. All you need is to create the dynamic event when your alarm goes off. The code in the dynamic event can change your text, if that is what you want. Please also read the help to understand DynEvents

Comment: Oh I've already managed to solve the problem but thank you so much for your kind assistance. 
Cheers!